# MILP BigM : variable must remains in defined boundaries or set to 0

Tags: linear-programming, pyomo

I'm modeling some energy systems via MILP / Pyomo.

In that context I'm modeling a bi-directional elec. converter.

Power/energy can flow in both ways:
However, In one way, the power P can only be within boundaries [LB;UB], otherwise it must be 0.

I use this formulation to ensure that:

LB - P <= LB * x

P <= UB * (1 - x)

x being a binary variable

and it seems to be working...

in the other way, the power P can only be within [-UB;-LB], otherwise 0.
but I'm struggling hard to ensure that, I just can't get the logic behind to build that kind of constraint...

Any help and explanation would be appreciated.

Thanks a lot,
Max

Answer (score 5):

I would think you have three states (or feasible regions):

```
 p = 0
 p ∈ [L,U]
 p ∈ [-U,-L]
```

I don't think that can be done with one binary variable.

You can do something like :

```
 δ1*L-δ2*U ≤ p ≤  δ1*U-δ2*L
 δ1+δ2 ≤ 1
 δ1,δ2 ∈ {0,1}
```

This is essentially:

```
 δ1=δ2=0    => p = 0
 δ1=1,δ2=0  => p ∈ [L,U]
 δ1=0,δ2=1  => p ∈ [-U,-L]
 δ1=δ2=1: not allowed
```

Comment: Adding a categorical degree of freedom is one the ways. Why introducing 2 binary variables and one rule instead of a 3 state one though?

Comment: @Learningisamess I don't know how to do that while keeping things linear so the poster can use his existing model and tools. Maybe you can show me how to do that.

Comment: I missed the constraint on linearity, I work with IP-OPT typically =)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll give it a try !

Comment: IP-OPT is spelled IPOPT. It is for continuous models only and is a local solver. It will not handle discrete variables. Note that even when formulated and an MINLP I would not use a single integer variable that can assume three values.  Even in that case, I would use 2 (or 3) binary variables. I think a single integer variable may only make sense when using a constraint programming (CP) solver.